# A JS algorithm to find point's location by checking if it is within fixed-size circles

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, geometry

So, I have a point in an unknown location, which I need to programmaticaly find. The only way we can try to find it's location is is by calling a special `isThePointWithin500MetersOfLocation(x, y)` function, which will return true if the point is within 500 meters of the passed location. I need to find out where the point is, or at least as close to it as possible. What algorithms could be used for this?

The `isThePointWithin500MetersOfLocation` function takes ~30 seconds to execute, so the less calls to it there are - the better.

The point is always checked to be within 500 meters of [0, 0] (`isThePointWithin500MetersOfLocation(0, 0)` is checked to always be true)

Comment: Do you start with a fixed area which you know that it is within?

Comment: Is this like a planet-scale Hunt the Wumpus and your goal is to narrow the location in as few steps as possible? Is this an interview question or something?

Comment: You need to set some constraints, like that the point starts always in the 500 meter distance from point x1, y1. Or some other constraint that limits the space. Otherwise, this becomes ugly and probably unsolvable (infinite space, no anchor point for initial guidance. In other words, `isThePointWithin500MetersOfLocation` covers only a finite part of an infinite space, and by definition you would need infinite calls to that function.

Comment: Remember to [show your code](/help/how-to-ask) (in [mcve] form) if you have code that you have questions about =) (also: 30 seconds?? A distance-between-points check for geo location takes not-even-a-millisecond, what on earth is that code doing?)

Comment: @btilly, oh yes, thanks for reminding me. the point is guaranteed to be within 500 meters of [0, 0] (isThePointWithin500MetersOfLocation(0, 0) is always checked to be true)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans it's an API that's rate limited to be accessible only once every 30 seconds.

Comment: @DaveNewton nope, this not an interview question, it's for a little proof of concept project. I'm trying to find device locations, by using an API in a certain chat messaging platform, that returns a list of users within 500 meters of some point. `isThePointWithin500MetersOfLocation` calls the API, and checks whether the target device is in that list. (This is a documented API, that they gave permission to use :0)

Comment: @Rea at that point I'm pretty sure you want to just take a day and write your own geoservice (speaking from experience, because I wrote one so I wouldn't have to rely on the open-elevation API). ALOS 30m resolution world data is free, and parsing geotiffs is a solved problem. And sure, [that'll take a day up front](https://github.com/Pomax/are-we-flying/blob/main/src/elevation/alos-server.js), but also means you may have just made this problem entirely moot (even if it's an interesting problem =)

Answer (score 0):

Let's skip over how you're going to find the *first* result for `isThePointWithin500MetersOfLocation`, because this sounds a little too much of a toy problem to fully solve, but once you have your first, start binary searching. Or since we're dealing with circles, and initial *trinary* searching: any circle of radius **r** can be fully covered by three circles with the same radius, with their centers on the original circle, and their centers each 120 degrees apart.

So let's do that:

```js
customElements.whenDefined(`graphics-element`).then(() => {

const graphics = document.getElementById(`illustration`);
  let code = circleGraphics.toString();
  code = code.substring(code.indexOf(`{`)+1, code.lastIndexOf(`}`));
  graphics.loadSource(code);
});

function circleGraphics() {
  let p, circles = [], current, a=0, s=TAU/3, nextButton, matches = [];
  let bisecting = false;

  function setup() {
    setSize(150, 150);
    let angle = random(0,TAU);
    let radius = random(0, 40);
    p = new Point(50, 50);
    current = new Circle(75, 75, 50)
    circles.push(current);
    matches.push(current);
    nextButton = addButton(`next`, tryNext);
  }

  function draw() {
    clear();
    setColor(`black`);
    point(p.x, p.y);
  
    if (bisecting) {
      matches.forEach(c => {
        setFill(c.fill ?? `#F001`);
        circle(c.x, c.y, c.r);
      });
      showBisection();
    } else {
      circles.forEach(c => {
        setFill(c.fill ?? `#F001`);
        circle(c.x, c.y, c.r);
      });
    }
    
    if (matches.length === 2 && !bisecting) {
      nextButton.remove();
      nextButton = addButton(`which means...`, () => {
        nextButton.remove();
        bisecting = true;
        redraw();
      });
    }
  }
  
  function showBisection() {
    // At this point we have reduced the area our
    // point can be in. How can we best bisect that?
    // By placing more circles, of course.
    //
    // And because the circles are the same radius,
    // finding the intersections is very easy:
    const [c1,c2] = matches;
    const { r } = c1;
    const a = atan2(c1.y - c2.y, c1.x - c2.x);
    
    // what are the intersection points between our two circles?
    setColor(`black`);
    const p1 = new Point(
      c1.x + r * cos(a - s),
      c1.y + r * sin(a - s),
    );
    const p2 = new Point(
      c1.x + r * cos(a + s),
      c1.y + r * sin(a + s),
    );
    
    // what's the normal vector for p1--p2?
    let dx = p2.x - p1.x;
    let dy = p2.y - p1.y;
    const mag = (dx**2 + dy**2)**0.5;
    dx /= mag;
    dy /= mag;
    
    // alright, let's look at our new area of interest:
    setColor(`#FFF9`);
    rect(0,0,width,height);
    setStroke(`#0C0`);
    setFill(`#0C03`);
    arc(c1.x, c1.y, r, a+s, a-s+TAU);
    arc(c2.x, c2.y, r, a+s+PI, a-s+PI);
    
    // with our intersection points and the line
    // through them as visual helpers:
    setColor(`black`);
    point(p.x, p.y);
    setColor(`#0004`);
    line(
      p1.x - huge * dx,
      p1.y - huge * dy,
      p2.x + huge * dx,
      p2.y + huge * dy
    );
    point(p1.x, p1.y);
    point(p2.x, p2.y);
  }  
  
  function tryNext() {
    const { x, y, r } = current;
    // Place a circle on the original circle perimeter, and
    // see if the point is in that new circle. If so, we've
    // narrowed the area it can be in.
    const c = new Circle(x + r * cos(a), y + r * sin(a), r);
    circles.push(c);
    const d = dist(c.x, c.y, p.x, p.y);
    const pointIsInCircle = d < c.r;
    if (pointIsInCircle) {
      c.fill = `#0F01`;
      matches.push(c);
      a = 0;
    } else {
      // no good, try next circle       
      a += s;
    }
    redraw();
  } 
}
```

```html
<script type="module" src="https://pomax.github.io/custom-graphics-element/dist/graphics-element.js"></script>
<link ref="stylesheet" href="https://pomax.github.io/custom-graphics-element/dist/graphics-element.css">
<graphics-element id="illustration"></graphics-element>
```

This is, of course, only the first iteration: once we have a two-circle overlap, we now get to figure out where to place two *new* circles that we can use to bisect the area of overlap. The trigonometry required to find the two centers of those circles, I will leave up to you.

Evaluating each of these two circles will either result in "point is in 1 of them", which will yield a "triangle-ish" shape, or "point is in *both* of them", in which case we have the exact same situation we were just in, just with a much smaller shape:

[image]

We can trisect and bisect those shapes, respectively, and thus we can get closer and closer and closer to the "true" location of our point. The implementation of which is an exercise for the <s>reader</s> poster =)

Comment: A binary search winds up being faster than trinary. Also the toy problem turned out be be more involved than I would have guessed. But I didn't quite finish writing down the complex optimal solution for how to do that.

Comment: Your first step _has_ to be trinary. You can't binary split your initial hit due to how circles work =D After that, though, binary away. Although I do have to point out that the "it takes 30 seconds to" part of the toy problem is _truly ridiculous_. I've written GeoTIFF solutions from scratch and they run literal orders (plural) of magnitude faster. Even in JS.

Comment: What are you referring to? Any region with nonzero area that fits within a circle of radius `r` can be split into two evenly by another circle of radius `r`. In fact this can happen in an infinite number of ways - one for each direction. Proof, if the circle covers the region, all of it is covered. As you move the circle, the area covered changes continuously. After `2r`, none is covered.  By the Intermediate Value Theorem, at some point it covers half.

Comment: If you switch between approximately vertical and horizontal splits, the shape of the region eventually approaches a rectangle of the same height/width ratio as standard paper.

Comment: You're going to have to find "the circle that the point is even in" first, then you trisect that because in this toy problem the test is _expensive_ at 30 seconds per test. We can't just "slide a circle over". In the real world: absolutely, just move the circle because it takes nanoseconds to test, you don't care. But In this particular toy problem: you don't have that luxury. The saving grace is that the smaller our enclosed area becomes, the more our circles approach acting as a straight line for the purpose of bisection, so the higher precision you need, the easier things get.

Comment: The sliding is onlt a mathematical model of a circle. It is after finding that halfway point that we call the function and get rid of half the region.

Comment: ah wait, I misread you. True, we can bisect from the start, though if you can start with the pointed ellipse, the actual "where do I place my next circle" is going to be a heck of a lot easier to compute than if you have to deal with a half-moon. For programming sanity, I'd definitely still start with the trisection and then bisect from there on.

Comment: Exactly. The binary search is possible, though hard. If you have to do the simple search, though you'll often find it with a circle that already has some inconvenient pieces cut out. So it's going to be hard to calculate no matter what you do.

Answer (score -3):

Here is testing for a point within a radius of another point.

```js
function testForPointInCircle(cx,cy, radius, tx,ty) {
        let dx = tx - cx;
        let dy = ty - cy;
        let distance = dx * dx + dy * dy;
        return distance < (radius * radius);
}
    
let p1 = {x:0, y:500};
let p2 = {x:25, y:450};

console.log( testForPointInCircle(p1.x,p1.y, 70, p2.x,p2.y), 
testForPointInCircle(p1.x,p1.y, 10, p2.x,p2.y) , p1.y );

let p3 = {x:10, y:1000};

//If you don't know the test point, you could call the function in a loop with a guess until you get true.

while( !testForPointInCircle(p3.x,p3.y, 25, p1.x,p1.y) ) {
    p1.y += 5;
}
console.log(p1.y);
```

Comment: That's what the function they have does.

Comment: Also, some very questionable JS going on here, did an AI write this? Because if not: testForPointInCircle has not been declared as variable, so that's a strict mode error. Also if it's a normal function, _just declare it as function_, not as a variable. Also, don't use `var`, it's been superceded by `let` and `const` due to `var`'s "crazy" scoping. Furthermore, you don't prefix globals with `window.`, and you don't need to concat strings with spaces for logging, just console log with multiple arguments and console.log adds the spaces between them. This is _very_ strange JS.